# Linker Error When Integrating iOS and the Google Plus SDK

Tags: ios, google-plus, linker-errors, armv7

I'm trying to use the Google Plus SDK for sharing in an iOS 6.1 app and get a linker error after adding the GooglePlus.framework and the GoogleOpenSource.framework.

Merely including the frameworks and building yields the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_CGRectDivide", referenced from:
  -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch moveWebViewFromUnderNavigationBar] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've followed instructions found in the [Google guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) to no avail.
I've done the following:

1. Included SystemConfiguration.framework and Security.framework
2. Dragged and dropped the GooglePlus.framework and the GoogleOpenSource.framework
   from the SDK into my XCode project
3. Added the -ObjC flag to the app target's build settings

In addition to the previous steps I also tried adding the contents of the OpenSource folder provided in the SDK but that <del>had no effect</del> caused additional problems after the initial fix.

Libraries:

[image: My included libraries]

Full error message:

```
 Ld "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-asdf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/
 Debug-iphoneos/MyAoo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp" normal armv7
     cd /Users/me/code/MyApp
     setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
     setenv PATH        

 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
 iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/ 
 Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
 XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/     
 Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk 

 -L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
 MyApp-asdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

 -L/Users/me/code/MyApp/MyApp 

 -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-asdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos 

 -F/Users/me/code/MyApp/../../Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Users/me/code/MyApp 

 -F/Users/me/code/MyApp/MyApp 

 -filelist "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/
 DerivedData/MyApp-asdf/Build/Intermediates/
 MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp.LinkFileList"

 -dead_strip -ObjC -lsqlite3.0 -fobjc-arc 
 -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 
 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security 
 -framework CFNetwork -framework Social -framework Accounts 
 -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI 
 -framework AVFoundation -framework MapKit  
 -framework Twitter -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation 
 -lxml2 -framework QuartzCore 
 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreData
 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation 
 -framework Pinterest -framework GooglePlus 
 -framework GoogleOpenSource 
 -lGooglePlusUniversal -o 

 "/Users/me/Library/Developer/
 Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-asdf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/
 Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp"

 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
   "_CGRectDivide", referenced from:
       -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch moveWebViewFromUnderNavigationBar] in 
   GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure what I missed but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also link in the CoreGraphics framework. It's looking for the CGRectDivide method, which is part of CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by adding OpenSource folder to you project, xcode detects that there is a duplication of files. So you should only add GooglePlus.framework and the GoogleOpenSource.framework.